# What is the problem with this for loop in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a function to calculate the sum of number which are multiples of 3.
What is the problem here, because I get numbers repeated 3 times until I get to 18, which is out of range. I don't understand.

```
summ = 0
for n in range(10):
    if n % 3 == 0:
         summ = summ+n
    print(summ)
```

Comment: You're printing in the loop, try printing after the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
summ = 0
for n in range(10):
    if n % 3 == 0:
         summ = summ+n

print(summ)
```

Your code `print(summ)` is inside the loop, meaning it will print multiple times (as many times as the loop runs). Moving it outside of the loop will only make it print once after the loop is done running.